# Updating an Integer doesn't work - why so?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

this is very weird. I have been trying to solve this issue for a while now. I am trying to do something very simple, update the message ID within an existing chat table entry.

check the code

```
public int updateLatestMessage(int messageID, int chatID){

    Log.d("DB", "messageid =" + messageID);  // messageID = 175
    Log.d("DB", "chatid =" + chatID); // chatID = 5

    testUpdate(chatID); // Testing if this Updates and it does update

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("last_message_id", messageID);

        int result = db.update("chat", cv, "chat_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(chatID)});
        db.close();
        return result;

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", "Error: "+e.toString());
        return 0;
    }

}
```

the function returns 1 meaning everything has updated correctly. But the message ID is still 10 as it was before instead of 175.

within the update function, I am running another update function to test if that works
which looks like this:

```
public void testUpdate(int chatID){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("chat_description", "Will this String Update");

    db.update("chat", cv, "chat_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(chatID)});
    db.close();
    return;


}
```

now this updates the string "Will this String Update" correctly.

the only difference as far as I can tell is that the message ID that I am trying to update and fail to do so, is an Integer. While the successful testUpdate updating the "chat_description", is a String.

What am I missing?

The error has to be in the code example I provided because I am logging the result directly before and after the update functions.

Comment: *Updating an Integer doesn't work* you are not updating an integer. You are updating only the column `chat_description`. *this updates the string "Will this String Update" correctly* so what is the problem? *The error has to be...* what error?

Comment: thanx for the reply, i am just updating the chat description for testing purposes by running the testUpdate() function within the updateLatestMessage() function. the updateLatestMessage() function  continues to attempt to update "last_message_id" which unfortunately fails (which is the issue).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: simply put "messageID" does not update "chat_description" does. in both cases SQL returns 1 which means update successfully. the only difference between the two values is that one is a String and the second is an Integer. (there is no error message, but unexpected output)

Comment: If *SQL returns 1* this means that the update is successful. If there is no change in the value this means that you updated the column with the same value it had.

Comment: I temporarily worked around the issue by storing the messageID into the chat description, just to keep development going. I am probably going to have to change the MessageID datatype to Text instead of Int. I still wonder why this is happening, seems odd

Comment: I totally agree with you, the weird thing is that I passed the message ID into the testUpdate function and stored it into chat_description and that works. so the value is different.

Comment: *I still wonder why this is happening, seems odd* what is happening?  If there is no error message then the code works fine. If the `updateLatestMessage()` method returns 1 then the update was successful. Either you do not explain correctly the *problem* or there is no problem.